# Call a route handler in Express conditional on query params

Tags: node.js, express

The external API I'm working with begins the OAuth2.0 process by sending users to our app's root with hmac and other query parameters (note this is PRIOR to the callback received when user authorization is granted). Therefore I want to serve my static site if there is no hmac parameter present, and call a handler function if it is. My validation code is working fine if I imbed all of it in the "else" statement of my app.get('/') route below. But I would prefer to clean it up and pass control to a separate handler function.

I get "TypeError res.redirect is not a function" with the example code below.

````
const morgan = require('morgan');

const app = express();
app.use(morgan('dev'));

app.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
    if (!req.query.hmac) {
        console.log('No special params. Serving static.');
        next();
    } else {
        console.log('handling hmac parameter');
        handleHmac(res, req);
    }
})

app.use(express.static('public'));

const handleHmac = (req, res) => {
    //validate hmac and ultimatley redirect to external auth site
    console.log('handleHmac function called')   //successfully prints in test
    res.redirect('/mockexternal.html')  //TypeError: res.redirect is not a function
}

app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Listening on Port 3000')
})```
````

Comment: Reversing the order of the parameters seems like a Bad Idea.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your function call `handleHmac(res, req);` to `handleHmac(req, res);`  The function arguments have to be in the right order.

I would recommend passing the third argument `next` also just so the handler is free to do anything a normal handler might do without changing the calling code.

```
handleHmac(req, res, next);
```